# Grow to fit available space, then eagerly wrap text instead of expanding parent

Tags: css, layout

Consider the example below, a tooltip or modal or something outside the normal layout flow where the container is able to grow, but should shrink to fit its contents. Here I would like the header (blue) to fit on a single line, (greedily) expanding the parent. That is, to behave like it normally would. But the "body text" (red) should only grow to fill the available space and then (eagerly) wrap the text.

Unfortunately there seems to be no obvious CSS property to express eagerly wrapping text layout.

```css
article {
  position: absolute;
  background: whitesmoke;
  padding: 1em 2em;
}

header {
  color: blue;
}

main {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <header>This should expand parent to fit.</header>
  <main>This should use available space, but wrap instead of expanding parent.</main>
</article>
```

*PS: This might just be my search or problem description skills being terrible, but I've not found anything even describing this problem, let alone the solution. Please link anything you can find that is related to this.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One trick I stumbled upon is to set `min-width: 100%` and then set `max-width` to the actual minimum value.

```css
min-width: 100%;
max-width: min-content; /* or even 0 */
```

You might think that setting `max-width: 100%` as well would work. Nope! I'm guessing because `100%` then would refer to the width after its "preferred" width has been applied.

I would love a proper explanation of why this works, but my understanding of it is simply that `max-width` overrides the internal "preferred" width, and then `min-width` overrides `max-width`. Seeing as this is CSS, I'm sure it's much more complicated though :)

```css
article {
  position: absolute;
  background: whitesmoke;
  padding: 1em 2em;
}

header {
  color: blue;
}

main {
  color: red;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <header>This should expand parent to fit.</header>
  <main>This should use available space, but wrap instead of expanding parent.</main>
</article>
```

Comment: Works fine in chrome, but for safari I had to use `max-width: 0` instead of `min-content`